# pushed Array undefined on ngAfterViewinit

Tags: arrays, angular, push, ngoninit

i have pushed some values on an Array on Angular ngOnInit and data became unusable on ngAfterViewInit, It shows the particular value as Undefined

```
randomNUMber = [];

 ngOnInit() {

this.apiServices.getLineChart(this.coinId).subscribe(resc => {

          for (let i =0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
            this.randomNUMber.push(Number(resc.data[i].price));
          }

          console.log('price1', this.randomNUMber[2]); //it Works
        });

}

ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log('price1', this.randomNUMber);  //this Wors too
console.log('price1', this.randomNUMber[2]); // But this doesnt work 
}
```

Comment: The `ngAfterViewInit` event handler is probably called before the `getLineChart` callback.

Comment: then how ```console.log('price1', this.randomNUMber); ``` works fine. it gets all the values

Comment: It is because the array content displayed in the console is evaluated when you click on the expand arrow. Try `console.log('price1', JSON.stringify(this.randomNUMber)));` to get the real-time content. You can also experiment with [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fesfwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), which shows that behavior.

Comment: What do you want to do in ngAfterViewInit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngOnInit() does not wait for async calls so you could do like :

```
...
this.myObs$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.myObs$ = this.apiServices.getLineChart(this.coinId).pipe(map(resc => {
      let randomNUMber: number[] = [];
      for (let i =0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
         randomNUMber.push(Number(resc.data[i].price));
      }

      return randomNUMber;
    }));
 }
```

If you use ngAfterViewInit, I guess you need to display this data correctly on your template.
So you need to use the async pipe to subscribe to this.myObs$

```
<div *ngIf="(myObs$ | async) as randomNUMber">
   <p *ngFor="let number of randomNUMber">
    {{ number }}
   </p>
</div>
```

See [Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Answer (score 1):

you have async call in ngOnInit which is not finished in time.